# Add Extra Text to Barcode Using Treepoem and BWIPP (Python)

Tags: python, barcode, ghostscript, postscript

I am generating barcodes using treepoem (and thus BWIPP), I want to have barcodes with their number below and other additional text above. I am trying to keep this all in the eps file generation rather than converting/editing in any other form as this is important for what I am doing with them after generating.

Below is my code as it stands (I have tried a variety of different options from the docs including `alttext`, but have been unsuccessful). I am using *Python 3.8.2* and *Treepoem 3.10.0*.

```
import treepoem # for barcode generation

def generate_rlb_barcode(barcode_type, barcode_data, image_name):

    eps_image = treepoem.generate_barcode(barcode_type, barcode_data, options={'includetext': True})
    print("image generation complete.")
    eps_image.convert('L')
    print("image converted to monochrome.")
    eps_image.save(image_name)
    print("image saved as " + str(image_name))

def main():
    barcode_image_name = 'test_img'
    generate_rlb_barcode('upca', '123456059973', (barcode_image_name + ".eps"))

main()
```

Answer (score 1):

**Install treepoem package:**

```
pip install treepoem
# or
python -m pip install treepoem
```

**Run this code**

```
import treepoem
image = treepoem.generate_barcode(
    barcode_type="code128",  # One of the BWIPP supported codes.
    data="Yout text-978316148fsd4100",
    options= {"includetext": True}
)
image.convert("1").save("output_qrcode_or_barcode.png")
```

[image: output_qrcode_or_barcode.png]

Answer (score 0):

To add further text you should

- create a white picture
- paste the barcode on it
- add texts

Generated picture:
[2D code with texts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsTM3.png)

Example code:

```
from treepoem import generate_barcode
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def generate_and_print(gtin, serial_number, expiry_date, batch_number):
    # Generate datamatrix
    datamatrix = generate_barcode(
        barcode_type='gs1datamatrix',
        data=f"(01){gtin}(21){serial_number}(17){expiry_date}(10){batch_number}",
        options={"parsefnc": True, "format": "square", "version": "26x26"})
    
    # Resize datamatrix to desired size
    dm_size_px = (120, 120)
    datamatrix = datamatrix.resize(dm_size_px, Image.NEAREST)

    # Create white picture
    picture_size_px = (500, 500)
    picture = Image.new('L', picture_size_px, color='white')

    # Position the datamatrix
    barcode_position_px = (180, 180)
    picture.paste(datamatrix, barcode_position_px)

    # Draw picture for placing texts on it
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(picture)

    # Store font for the texts
    ocrb_font = ImageFont.truetype("OCRBPro.TTF", 18)
    # Draw texts on the Picture
    datamatrix_text_position_px = (100,100)
    draw.text(datamatrix_text_position_px, "This is a GS1 DataMatrix", fill='black', font=ocrb_font)
    welcome_text_position_px = (150,400)
    draw.text(welcome_text_position_px, "You are welcome", fill='black', font=ocrb_font)

    # Save the image
    picture.save("datamatrix.png")

gtin = "01234567890128"
serial_number = "01234567891011"
expiry_date = "250731"
batch_number = "DATAMATRIXTEST"

generate_and_print(gtin, serial_number, expiry_date, batch_number)
```